# Mule to JPA compatibility

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, mule

I using Mule Studio version: 1.3.1 .

buildDate: 201209061215

I am not able to get JPA end point. I also downloaded `jpa-connector-1.0-20120925-2201.jar`
But I dont know to to integrate with mule studio.

So I decided to use a simple Java transformer and write my processing logic which will be internally using JPA/Hibernate.

I came to know that i have to use a JPA vendor adapter for spring, else none of my service, DAO classes will be instantiated.

I have declared a datasource and entityManager as beans of spring inside mule flow xml as shown.

```
<spring:bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                <spring:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <spring:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eigDB" />
                <spring:property name="username" value="root" />
                <spring:property name="password" value="tiger" />
        </spring:bean>

        <spring:bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <spring:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <spring:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="autoRebateSystem" />
        <spring:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <spring:bean
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <spring:property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
                <spring:property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </spring:bean>
```

But mule flow xml is not able to recognize any class of spring framework.
Finding very difficult to replace those class names.

Plez provide the solution for my problem, 
By letting me know the PROPER replacements for mule studio.

```
1) org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
2) org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
3) org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter
```

Comment: When you talk about the JPA do you refer at the one available here: http://code.google.com/p/mule-transport-jpa/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing to use `HibernateJpaDialect` and `JpaTransactionManager`; 
I hope the following configuration will be useful.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdatabase"/>
    <property name="username" value="your- username"/>
    <property name="password" value="your- password"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>


<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<!--<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>-->
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="<your-persistunit-name>"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect/>
    </property>
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver">
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform"/>
<!--        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform" />-->
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
    <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

To integrate it within MuleStudio, please add this update site within MuleStudio:

http://tecnologia.2020mobile.es/jpa-cloud-connector/update-site/